# Postion widget with grid in tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to create a Form and on first page I am asking about username and password. I am using grid and putting rows but tkinter is not taking the row which I want. Please find the code below :-

```
import tkinter as tk

class Passwordchecker(tk.Frame):
   def __init__(self, parent):
      tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
      self.parent = parent
      self.initialize_user_interface()

   def initialize_user_interface(self):

      self.parent.resizable(False, False)  # This code helps to disable windows from resizing
      window_height = 120
      window_width = 210
      screen_width = self.winfo_screenwidth()
      screen_height = self.winfo_screenheight()
      x_cordinate = int((screen_width / 2) - (window_width / 2))
      y_cordinate = int((screen_height / 2) - (window_height / 2))
      self.parent.geometry("{}x{}+{}+{}".format(window_width, window_height, x_cordinate, y_cordinate))

      self.parent.title("MN Creater")

      self.label = tk.Label(self.parent, text="Username : ")
      self.label.grid(row=9, column=0)
      self.entry = tk.Entry(self.parent)
      self.entry.grid(row=1, column=1)

      self.label = tk.Label(self.parent, text="Password : ")
      self.label.grid(row=3, column=0)
      self.entry = tk.Entry(self.parent)
      self.entry.grid(row=3, column=1)


if __name__ == '__main__':

 root = tk.Tk()
 root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Tkinter is "taking" the row that you give it. Rows and columns that are empty have a size of zero, so whether you put it at row 9 or row 9000, it will still appear right below the last row with something in it.

Comment: If I want to put the username and password in between the form. how to do that.